# Get All Rows Created In the Past Five Minutes in Ruby Sequel

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I am using Ruby Sequel and I would like to retrieve all rows created in the past n-number of seconds. So let's say I have 5 rows created the past 300 seconds (5 minutes), I would like to retrieve all of it.

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `timestamp` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 300 SECONDS
```

P.S. the reason I use `N SECONDS` is because I am using ActiveSupport's Time library which lets me use abstractions like `5.minutes` or `5.hours` which all gets converted to the number of seconds.

But I am not quite sure how to convert this to Sequel

Comment: MySQL also supports MINUTES..   `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTES` is eazer to read then 300 SECONDS.

Comment: Well, for my thing, I am using the ActiveSupport [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html) library which lets a user specify things like `5.minutes` or `2.hours` which in the end all gets converted to seconds. So in this case, it's fine to use `INTERVAL - x SECONDS`!

Answer (score 0):

```
MyApp::Model::MyClass.where {created_at >= Time.now - interval}
```

Where `interval` is the number of seconds